# If $f_n,f$ are holomorphic and $f_n\to f$ uniformly on compacta, then $f'_n\to f'$ uniformly on compacta

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

> Let $f,f_n:D(0,1)\to\mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic. Suppose $f_n$ converges uniformly on compacta to $f$. Show that $f'_n$ converges uniformly on compacta to $f'$.

I started with trying manipulating $|f'_n(z)-f'(z)|$ with a boundary $|f(z)|\leq M$ for all $z$ in a compact set $S\subset D(0,1)$, but it doesn't seem to lead to anything. I would like for some help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $z_0\in D(0,1)$ and $r>0$ such that $\lvert z-z_0\rvert<r\implies z\in D(0,1)$. Then, if $\lvert z-z_0\rvert<r$,$$f(z)=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\lvert z-z_0\rvert=r}\frac{f(\eta)}{\eta-z}\,\mathrm d\eta.$$Since the set $\{z\in\mathbb C\,|\,\lvert z-z_0\vert=r\}$ is compact, it follows from this that $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $D(z_0,r)$.

Now, if $K\subset D(0,1)$ is compact, all you have to do is to consider, for each $z_0\in K$ a disk $D(z_0,r)\subset K$. Since $K$ is compact, it can be covered by finitely many such disks and now you can use the fact that the convergence is uniform on each such disk to prove that the convergence is uniform on $K$.

In order to prove that $(f_n')_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges uniformly to $f'$ on each compact, you use the same idea, together with the formula$$f'(z)=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\lvert z-z_0\rvert=r}\frac{f(\eta)}{(\eta-z)^2}\,\mathrm d\eta.$$

Comment: Thanks. I understood that $\boldsymbol{f_n}$ is convergent but I didn's realized why does $\boldsymbol{f'_n}$ convergent.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is clear now.

Comment: @J.Doe So this is really a consequence of the Cauchy integral formula relating the values of all the derivatives with those $f$ on a slightly large circle

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I didn't understand; Let $K\subset D(0,1)$ be a compact set. Then there's $z_0\in K$ such that $D(0,1)\supset D(z_0,r)\supset K$. So we need to show that $f'_n\to f'$ uniformly on $D:=D(z_0,r)$. Let $z\in D$.
$$|f'_n(z)-f'(z)|=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\gamma_{z_0,r}}\frac{f_n(\omega)-f(\omega)}{(z_0-\omega)^2}d\omega \\ \leq r\cdot \max \frac{f_n(\omega)-f(\omega)}{(z_0-\omega)^2}$$
But how can I bound $M:=\frac{f_n(\omega)-f(\omega)}{(z_0-\omega)^2}$?